# Extract only the text with a background color of a word-file to python

Tags: python, docx

I want to extract "highlighted" text from a word-file into python.

I know how to extract the full document in black and white with:

```
import docx2txt
my_text = docx2txt.process('path')
print(my_text)
```

Then i get the full document back. But in the original word file there are some highlighted tables which green background color (the full tables are green background color), how can I extract that information only?

Comment: Please read tag descriptions before using them. [tag:word]: *"A word is the amount of data that a processor can fit in its general-purpose registers -- effectively the amount of data the processor can handle "at once". __Programming-related questions concerning Microsoft Word should NOT use this tag - use the tag [ms-word] instead__"*

Comment: @PV8 you are using wrong library for procesing docx files. `docx2txt` only convert files to text. You need advanced docx processor, I think that you may be interested in using `python-docx` package

Comment: Generally you should parse docx file, and for each word in paragraph, check backlight of word -> then for highlighted words, extract them to list, then save list to txt file

Answer (score 0):

Use python-docx for this. For text highlighted in a certain color, see https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/text.html#docx.text.run.Font.highlight_color

```
import docx

document = docx.Document("disk.docx")


tables = document.tables

for table in tables:
    for row in table.rows:
        for cell in row.cells:
            for paragraph in cell.paragraphs:
                for run in paragraph.runs:
                    if run.font.highlight_color:
                        print(run.text)
```

Edit : Edited for extracting text from tables.

Comment: thx for the answer, but this does not create any output